# Restar los valores de una columna con los de otra hasta cierto punto en un dataframe en R

Tags: r, dataframe

Me podrían ayudar si son tan amables?
Tengo un dataframe en R con tres variables (X, Y y S), como se muestra abajo. 
Deseo agregar una columna llamada "R" que cuando una celda de la columna "S" sea igual a "A", haga una resta de los valores de la columna "Y" con los valores de la columna "X" iniciando en S "A" hasta antes donde aparece otra celda en la columna "S" con una próxima letra "A" o "B", colocando en la celda de la columna "R" que corresponde, solamente si el resultado de las restas echas es -2 o 6 (cual de los dos resulte primero. Y cuando aparezca otra letra haga lo mismo hasta el final.

Si el resultado de todas las restas hechas no dan como resultado "-2" o "6" se coloca 0.

Ejemplo: En la segunda fila aparece la letra "A" en la columna "S". Debo restar 5 - 4 = 1, 2 - 4 = -2, 10 - 4 = 6 y 11 - 4 = 7

Los dos números "-2" y "6" resultan de la resta pero como "-2" ocurre primero, ese es el valor que se coloca.

Gracias

1. X  Y   S   R
2. 3  4     -       -
3. 4  5     A      -2
4. 6  2     -       -
5. 8  10    -       -
6. 12 11    -       -
7. 10  8    B       0
8. 5   9    -       -
9. 7   6    -       -
10. 2   7    -       -
11. 6   9    -       -
12. 8  15    A       6
13. 1  14    -       -
14. 4   3    -       -
15. 12  1    B       0
16. 10  8    -       -
17. 8   7    -       -
18. 6   1    -       -
19. 5   4    -       -

[image: Resultado final]

Comment: Bienvenido alejo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Dices: "Los dos números -2 y 6 resultan de la resta pero como "-2" ocurre primero, ese es el valor que se coloca.", ¿qué significa?, ¿que cada grupo de datos que comiencen con A a partir del primero llevarán un 2? ayudaría muchísimo si escribes un ejemplo de como debería ser la salida final a partir del ejemplo que has dado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, en una columna de un dataframe no puede haber celdas vacías como en la figura. La columna numérica R tendrá valores NA en las celdas vacías. La columna S que tiene valor "-" en la pregunta, tampoco puede tener caracteres vacíos, podría tener espacio vacío "" pero es un caracter. Por cierto, la columna con caracteres en un df es por defecto de tiupo factor. 
Supongo que debe haber varias formas de hacer esto que necesitas. El código comentado que doy abajo creo que funciona, al menos con algunos ejemplos que probé.

```
addColumnR <- function(df) {
  # Debo tener un rango rng de indices de df$Y tal
  # el primero coincide con la fila de la "A", y el ultimo
  # con el anterior a una A o una B
  aes <- (1:nrow(df))[df$S == "A"]
  bes <- (1:nrow(df))[df$S == "B"]

  # esta funcion calula el valor a asignar
  restas <- function(rng, df) {
    out <- df[rng, 2] - df[rng[1], 1]
    # busco si hay un -2 o un 6
    out <- out[out == -2 | out == 6]
    # si no encontre devuelvo 0, sino el primero
    if (length(out) == 0 ) out <- 0
    out[1]
  }

  # esta función me devuelve el rango de subindices
  # de Y entre una A
  rangos <- function(x, df) {
    bes <- (1:nrow(df))[df$S == "B" | df$S == "A"]
    seq(x, min(bes[bes > x]) - 1,  1)
  }
  # calculo los rangos necesarios
  rngs <- lapply(aes, rangos, df)
  # calculo los valores -2, 6 o ceros para las A
  valores <- sapply(rngs, restas, df)
  # genero un vector de NAs
  R <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
  # reemplazo los valores para las Aes
  R[aes] <- valores
  # a las Bes les asigno cero
  R[bes] <- 0
  # devuelvo el df con la columna R 
  cbind(df, R)
}
# ejemplo con el df1 de la pregunta
> addColumnR(df1)
    X  Y S  R
1   3  4 - NA
2   4  5 A -2
3   6  2 - NA
4   8 10 - NA
5  12 11 - NA
6  10  8 B  0
7   5  9 - NA
8   7  6 - NA
9   2  7 - NA
10  6  9 - NA
11  8 15 A  6
12  1 14 - NA
13  4  3 - NA
14 12  1 B  0
15 10  8 - NA
16  8  7 - NA
17  6  1 - NA
18  5  4 - NA
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien con los datos del ejemplo en R. Gracias Marcelo Fernando Befumo.